# Inserir espaço em uma variável PHP

Tags: php

Olá vejo que é uma questão muito simples aparentemente mas estou encontrando muita dificuldade em fazer isso, provavelmente devo estar olhando de forma errado sobre o assunto, o que estou tentando fazer é o seguinte:

```
$var3 = $var1." ".$var2;
```

No caso a var3 receberia a string var1 + var2 com um espaço entre elas, porém dessa forma não consigo alcançar o que quero, alguma forma de fazer isso nesse estilo? (de forma simples).

**EDIT:**
Testei o código e agora funcionou, provavelmente devia ter tido algum erro na hora da execução.

Comment: Se `$var3` não recebe o que você quer, então o que você quer? Não é o espaço entre os valores de `$var1` e `$var2`?

Comment: O que eu quero é que ela receba a var1 + var2 com um espaço entre elas, por exemplo se o o conteudo de var1 for carro e de var2 for placa o resultado sai o seguinte: carroplaca porém eu quero que saia carro placa (com espaço entre elas).

Comment: $var1 e $var2 tem valor?

Comment: @Wel O código da pergunta gera o resultado sem o espaço? Tem certeza absoluta disso? [Veja isso](https://repl.it/repls/SardonicExhaustedGermanshepherd)...

Comment: Tente esse exemplo: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.operators.string.php

Comment: No meu teste ao menos sim (estou usando a versão 5 do php se isso fizer diferença).

Comment: @Wel Não faz, o resultado é o mesmo, com o espaço, em todas as versões, desde a 4.3.0, no mínimo. [Ver detalhes](https://3v4l.org/JrAS7).

Comment: Realmente testei com a mesma situação e funcionou aqui.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

você pode usar a função `sprintf`, veja:

```
$var1 = "Olá";
$var2 = "Mundo";
$var3 = sprintf("%s %s", $var1, $var2);
echo $var3; // Olá Mundo
```

Você pode usar quantos parâmetros quiser na função `sprintf` que o `PHP` vai colocar na sequencia que você definir:

```
$texto = sprintf("%s %s %s %s", $var1, $var2, "Outra mensagem", "final");
echo $texto; // Olá Mundo Outra mensagem final
```

Veja a [documentação completa desta função](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.sprintf.php)

Comment: `$var3 = "{$var1} {$var2}"` deixa o código muito mais legível :D

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss prefiro usar a função, acho que já é um costume, tanto é que as vezes uso outros `placeholders` como `%d`, `%f` e assim não preciso ficar convertendo inteiros para float e etc...

Comment: gostaria de saber o porque dos `-1`;  por favor caso discordem ou algo esteja errado envie aqui nos comentários.